# how to centre a linearlayout inside linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I have a linearlayout and in it another linearlayout.

How can I centre the son in its parent?

these didn't help:

`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

`android:layout_gravity="center"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_widget_nodata_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_info1">

    <!--
        ========================================================================
        * Information layout - contains the explanation text on the background 
        ========================================================================
    -->


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:text="@string/widget_nodata_title"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_btn_enter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/widget_no_data_accept"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_btn_close"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/widget_no_data_close"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried the following, unsuccessfully:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

I prefer not to complicate things and to not add another layer of inner RelativeLayout

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: what about android:gravity="center"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either try to use:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in the parent layout or

`layout_gravity`

in the child layout.

The difference between gravity and layout_gravity is that gravity defines the position inside the view for the content or its children and layout_gravity outside the view for the view itself.

Or just replace the parent `LinearLayout` with a `RelatieLayout` and use

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

in the child.

Comment: gravity="center" must be set on the parent LinearLayout.

Comment: @StephaneMathis, I'm always get confused with this one, so I play with it until I get the desired result. If you sure about this one then you are welcome to edit the answer : )

Comment: what do you mean by it didn't work? what is your expected result and what do you have now?

Comment: @EmilAdz I have added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` add values sequentially, so the `inner-LinearLayout's` position will be based on the previous child's position, but you can center all childs of that `outer-LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_widget_nodata_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_with_logo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp" >


 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >
```

Or u can use relative layout

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"  -------------- need to remove
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_btn_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/widget_no_data_close"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
```